# What might delete keys from Redis?

Tags: redis

We have 3 apps on our server. They talk to each other via Redis. Redis is the bus for all communication.

Something on our server is incorrectly deleting keys from Redis. I am trying to track down the problem. For each app, I downloaded the code to my machine, and then tried:

```
grep -iR "flush" *
grep -iR "del" *
```

Two of the apps are free of "flush" and "del". Only one app has "del". So I found its PID and:

```
kill -9 2312
```

I also did "ps aux" to make sure that app was off.

The other 2 apps only have:

```
hset
hget
hmgetall
```

The disappearance of the keys in Redis is erratic. Some keys last several minutes, or even hours. Others disappear quickly.

As near as I can see, none of the developers have set timeouts on the keys in Redis. But maybe something sets a default timeout?

How do I debug this? Where do I look?

Comment: Open a redis-cli connection to your server and run `MONITOR` to see which commands are sent. Look at the output of `INFO KEYSPACE` to understand if there are any expired keys. Perhaps you're running out of memory and your eviction policy kicks out your keys?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do take a look at Redis configuration:

```
config get maxmemory*
```

Be sure that maxmemory is large enough for your dataset otherwise keys will be automatically dropped with the [**specified maxmemory-policy**](http://redis.io/topics/lru-cache).